# How to fix the most common LazyInitializationException - Hibernate JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, lazy-initialization

I'm struggling with LazyInitializationException. I've read so far literally every article about that, but unfortunately I didn't find solution for my problem. Many of those solutions using EntityManager or things which I don't using. I'm connecting with my DB via JPA.

I've got couple of entities, but the problem is just with two of them: Order and OrderDetails.
When I get from DB object Order, and then I'll try to do order.getOrderDetails() then I gettin following error:

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.tradesystem.order.Order.orderDetails, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

but it works the other way around: from OrderDetails object I can get Order by objectDetail.getOrder() .
What's more: I can't use Eager loading due to fact that I'm using it in another entity.

Here's my Order class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "orders")
public class Order {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "order_id")
private Long id;

private LocalDate date;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
private List<OrderDetails> orderDetails;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "buyer_fk")
private Buyer buyer;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "supplier_fk")
private Supplier supplier;
}
```

OrderDao:

```
@Repository("orderDao")
public interface OrderDao extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {

@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM orders " +
        "WHERE MONTH(orders.date) = ?1 AND YEAR(orders.date) = ?2",
        nativeQuery = true)
List<Order> getMonthOrders(int month, int year);
}
```

and OrderDetails:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "orderDetails")
public class OrderDetails {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "order_details_id")
private Long id;

private BigDecimal quantity;

private BigDecimal sum;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "order_fk")
private Order order;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "product_fk")
private Product productType;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "order_comment_fk")
private OrderComment orderComment;
}
```

Relationship that finished with @Many is Lazy loaded by default, so why it doesn't load my OrderDetails when I doing .getOrderDetails() ?

I will be really gratefull for any help! 
PS. I'm begginer, so if I didn't explain something enough good, don't hestitate to make some questions.

Comment: When are you getting the exception ? Is it in a Service ? A controller ? Is it a Transactional Context ?

Comment: In service. No, it isn't Transactional Contex.

Comment: Do you **really have** to use native queries? else you could use `left join fetch order.orderDetails`

Comment: So what do you propose exactly instead of native queries?

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
@Repository("orderDao")
public interface OrderDao extends JpaRepository<Order, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT orders FROM Order orders LEFT JOIN FETCH orders.orderDetails " +
        "WHERE MONTH(orders.date) = ?1 AND YEAR(orders.date) = ?2")
    List<Order> getMonthOrders(int month, int year);
}
```

Comment: But it should. Maybe you can share the new exception? All orders returned by this method should have their orderDetails collection initialized.

Comment: The new exception is exactly same as before, nothing changed. JOIN FETCH  while geting Order object should load objectDetails in same time, but it doesn't.

Comment: Are all orders affected or only a few? When using OSIV you have to be careful as entity object that are already part of the session/entity manager are not initialized when using join fetching.

Comment: Doesn’t matter how many orders I’m trying to get, same problem is when I’m just retrieving  a particular order (by id) or couple of them (by selected month).

Comment: Fetch joining will retrieve the state from the database. The only reason why the collection is not initialized is if that order object comes from the first or second level cache. It could be part of the first level cache if you loaded the order within the transaction before without the fetch joining. I can only recommend you try to clear the entity manager before doing this query to be sure or debug right before the query is executed to inspect what is in the first level cache. Without more details or a sample project this is hard to remote diagnose

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that problem. I was running everything in CommandLineRunner. Lazy Exception disappeared when I started making tests insted of "trying something" in main class.

My main class looked like:

```
 @Bean
 public CommandLineRunner bookDemo(OrderDao orderDao, PriceDao priceDao, ProductDao productDao,
                                   OrderService orderService, InvoiceDao invoiceDao, InvoiceService invoiceService) {
                                   OrderService orderService, InvoiceDao     invoiceDao, InvoiceService invoiceService,
                                   ReportService reportService) {
     return (args) -> {

         List<Order> orders = orderDao.findByBuyerId(1L);

         for (Order order : orders) {
             orderService.payForOrde(order);
         }
```